# converting docker link commands into docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to convert the below commands into a `docker-compose.yml` file?

```
$ docker run --name venns-mongo -v /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/mongodata:/data/db -d -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest

$ docker run -d --name venns -p 6001:6001 --link venns-mongo -v /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2 -e MONGO_HOST=venns-mongo lufang0411/orthovenn2:latest

$ docker run --name venns-front -p 9999:80 --link venns -v /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2 -e API_HOST=venns -e API_PORT=6001 -d lufang0411/orthovenn2-front:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have 2 versions of docker-compose that relevant to your commands:

```yaml
# Exact convert
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: venns-mongo
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/mongodata:/data/db
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017

  orthovenn2:
    image: lufang0411/orthovenn2:latest
    container_name: venns
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2
    ports: 
      - 6001:6001
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=venns-mongo
  
  front:
    image: lufang0411/orthovenn2-front:latest
    container_name: venns-front
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2
    ports: 
      - 9999:80
    environment:
      - API_HOST=venns
      - API_PORT=6001

# recommended
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/mongodata:/data/db
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017

  orthovenn2:
    image: lufang0411/orthovenn2:latest
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2
    ports: 
      - 6001:6001
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=db
  
  front:
    image: lufang0411/orthovenn2-front:latest
    volumes:
      - /mnt/volume1/orthovenn/venn2data:/data/orthovenn2
    ports: 
      - 9999:80
    environment:
      - API_HOST=orthovenn2
      - API_PORT=6001
```

Note that docker `link` is deprecated, with docker-compose by default all containers will be put inside  `default` network and can reach each others